# UIView setTransform and CGRect applying(transform) is not equivalent?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I want the CGRect transformed. My first code was using UIView. But I realize I should not use UIKit object in my code.
Finally I found CGRect has [applying(transform) method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1455875-applying). Looks great. But the results are not equivalent.

```
var f = CGRect(x: 10, y: 30, width: 100, height: 200)
let v = UIView(frame: f)
let t = CGAffineTransform(a: 0.96190500259399414, b: -0.27338498830795288, c: 0.27338498830795288, d: 0.96190500259399414, tx: 181.20297241210938, ty: 345.42660522460938)

// 1: transform using uiview.
v.transform = t
v.frame // {x 165.769 y 365.567 w 150.867 h 219.719}

// 2: transform using applying method
f.applying(t) // {x 199.024 y 344.211 w 150.867 h 219.719}
```

1 and 2 is not same.
1 is the correct result for me.
How should I get CGRect transformed without using UIView?

Comment: I know, very late reply. You have to take a look at the underlying coordinate systems. In this case probably different origins.